# Navigating to a certain page if user enters an url from a new tab

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router, canactivate

I have built a loginPageGuard which simply not letting user lo login page if it is already logged in.

Lets say user is on

```
http://localhost:4200/#/testUrl
```

and tries to go to 
`http://localhost:4200/#/login`

LoginPageGuard works as i want it to and user stays on

```
http://localhost:4200/#/testUrl
```

The problem is when user is logged in and opens a new tab and enter following URL in browser

```
http://localhost:4200/#/login
```

App doesn`t let the user to login page but goes to

```
http://localhost:4200/#/
```

What i want is to take to user to

```
http://localhost:4200/#/someDesiredUrl
```

Is there any way to achieve this ? Thanks

**LoginPageGuard**

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginPageGuard implements CanActivate {


  constructor(private router: Router, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

    return this.authenticationService.isAuthorized()
      .map((user:EUser)=>{
      return !user.isAuthorized;
    })
  }
}
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
  {
    path: 'login',
    canActivate:[LoginPageGuard],
    component: LoginComponent
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the injected router instance to navigate to `someDesiredUrl`?

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
      //Authentication logic here
      //If already logged in
      this.router.navigateByUrl('someDesiredUrl');
}
```

Comment: I only want user to go to some desired URL if users opens a new tab and tries to go to login page. Otherwise the system works fine..